# How to allow "read more" tag when using custom excerpts no wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I am trying to figure out how to have wordpresss automatically add a read more tag when I'm using a custom excerpt on wordpress posts. I want to use custom excerpts since it allows the html (links, bold, etc) to display on the home page of the blog.

Thanks in advance for your help, and please let me know if you'd like me to post any code from my existing theme.

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is to use the ["more" quick tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More).

You just type `<!--more-->` at the point in the post where you'd like the post to be truncated. On pages where multiple posts are displayed (such as your blog page), it will only show the content up to that point, then insert a "Read more" link automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I want the more tag to display with the custom excerpts. I have a youtube video at the top of my posts that I do not want embedded on the top of the post on the home page. I just want the text that I entered into the custom excerpt area to show up